# Can't force DataGridView generate columns

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating both datatable and datagridview on the fly and simply want the grid to generate columns from that table.

```
// create simple datatable
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView() { AutoGenerateColumns = true };

// None of the below force datagridview to generate columns
dgv.DataSource = dt;
Debug.WriteLine($"Grid columns count: {dgv.Columns.Count}");
dgv.DataSource = new BindingSource(dt, null);
Debug.WriteLine($"Grid columns count: {dgv.Columns.Count}");
```

Columns count in data grid view is still zero after I set datasource.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you adding the grid to? Try adding the grid to the form and the columns should display. The `DataGridView` is a UI control and it won’t add the columns/rows until it is displayed.

Comment: `private BindingSource source = null;` (as a field) `source = new BindingSource() { DataSource = dt }; dgv.DataSource = source;`. As a field so you can access it later. If you don't need it later (for the CurrencyManager or something else), declare it in-place. You can always cast `dgv.DataSource` to BindingSource.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a DataTable and give it some columns then add this DataTable as datagridview columns

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
```

Once you declared it build a functions such this:

```
void createDataTable()
{
    dt.Columns.Add("column1");
    dt.Columns.Add("column2");
    yourdatagridview.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Last call the function in your form cunstructor:

```
createDataTable();
```